# Magento 2 - Load .css file on checkout page

Tags: magento2, layout, css, magento2.3.4

I need to load the css file **THEME\Magento_Checkout\web\css\checkout\index\index.css** in the checkout page only.

So I created the file **THEME\Magento_Checkout\layout\checkout_index_index.xml** and added a layout instruction:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Magento_Checkout::css/checkout/index/index.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

I can see in the source code that it tries to load the script, but if I open it then I get

> Compilation from source: LESS file is empty:
>   frontend/company/base/de_DE/css/checkout/index/index.less

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by executing `grunt clean`. Now after loading the source code site again, it shows

**https://example.com/pub/static/version1584630764/frontend/company/base/de_DE/Magento_Checkout/css/checkout/index/index.css"**

instead of

**https://example.com/pub/static/version1584630764/frontend/company/base/de_DE/css/checkout/index/index.css"**

and it works.

---

**Hint**: If you don't use grunt, then you will have to manually delete the folders `pub/static/frontend` and `var/view_preprocessed`